# Source Medium google cpc and landing page

Tags: google-analytics

When i go to google analytics and go to the following page

- Acquisition > Source / Medium
- set the traffic filter to : Source / Medium: google / cpc
- set the secondary dimension to Landing page.

There are a lot landing pages listed for which no advertising campaing exists. The combination source / medium: google cpc and landing page does not exist. Does anyone know why these landing pages do pop up.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on google's last non-direct click attribution by default. That means that if a user clicked on your campaign on Sunday and initiated a session he will be counted as google / cpc with landing page the one from your campaign.
Now if the user comes on Monday from **direct** only he will be having source/medium = google / cpc and the landing page of his current visit. That is how the default attribution works in GA. The campaigns get the attribution until a non-direct visit is initialized from the user. This persists based on a property setting named Campaign Timeout and can be found here:
Admin --> Property --> Tracking Info --> Session Settings.
More explanation can be found in GA [advertiser community](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Tracking-Goals/Last-Non-Direct-Click-Attribution-Model-Question/td-p/568291#) and [support.google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1665189?hl=en)